# Filter letter by letter on Array Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, lodash, typescript2.0

I am trying to filter letter by letter on an array as below

MyJSON

```
"mainArr":[  
       {  
          "data":false,
          "myArr":[  
             {  
                "myNumber": 12345,
             },
             {
                "myNumber": 8961,
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

And here is code which I am drafting below for search but unable to pick object based on letter keypress or key down or ion-input

```
    if (filterVal && filterVal.trim() !== '') {
        this.myArray = this.myArray.filter(function (item) {
          const results: any = [];
          const obj = item.mainArr[0];
          if (_.has(obj, 'myArr')) {
            console.log(obj.myArr.indexOf(filterVal));

            for (let i = 0; i < obj.myArr.length; i++) {
               if (obj.myArr.indexOf(filterVal) !== -1)
                 return results.push(obj.myArr[i]);
               }
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

[Refered URL](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/demos/src/searchbar/pages/page-one/page-one.ts)

Comment: `MainArr` -> `mainArr`. Remove `any` from your code as it is providing you with a false sense of security.

Answer (score 0):

Tried another way of implementing it, but backspace is not re-binding to original array

```
let results: any = [];
events.subscribe('filterSearch', (filterVal: string) => {
  if (filterVal && filterVal.trim() !== '') {
    results = Object.assign(this.allEventsSorted.filter(function (item: any): any {
      const fltDty = item.mainArr[0];

      if (_.has(fltDty, 'myArr')) {
        return _.some(
          item.mainArr[0].myArr,
          function (tag): any {
            return _.startsWith(tag.myNumber, filterVal);
            // return _.includes(tag.myNumber, filterVal);
          }
        );
      }
    }));
    this.allEventsSorted = results;
  }
});
```